# Check Remote File for String

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, grep

I need to check a remote file for a specific string. The result of this check will provide a condition for an `if` statement in a local bash script:

**Attempted Code:**

```
if ssh user@ip.add.ress.here "grep -qxF "NO CAUTION FLAGS" /home/user/public_html/some/directory/here/text.file";
then
echo "Ok"
URL="http://www.websiteurl.com/ok.png"
else
echo "Bad"
URL="http://www.websiteurl.com/bad.png"
fi
```

The result is `Bad` when it is expected to be `Ok`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter makes this an easy one: you've misunderstood how quoting works in Bash. (Actually the syntax highlighter doesn't grasp it properly, either, but in this case it's enough to show you your mistake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape your quotes:

```
if ssh user@ip.add.ress.here "grep -qxF \"NO CAUTION FLAGS\" /home/user/public_html/some/directory/here/text.file";
```